# Why does VSCode give me a type error on this subscription?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rxjs, typescript-typings, subscription, aws-amplify

I'm following this tutorial https://aws.github.io/aws-amplify/media/api_guide#subscriptions with my VSCode.

My VSCode keeps telling me there is an error on the `subscribe` method.

When I look at the definition of the `graphql` method, it tells me `graphql({query, variables}: GraphQLOptions): Promise<GraphQLResult> | Observable<object>;`

It can return a promise or an Observable. Well I'm trying to subscribe to this observable. What am I doing wrong? Why does VSCode keep telling me there is an error there?

[image]

The error is: `'subscribe' property does not exist in type 'Promise<GraphQLResult> | Observable<object>'.`

Do I have to configure something in my `tsconfig.json`?

**EDIT: Add a screen of the definition of `graphql` method.**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typescript error is correct: the `.subscribe()` method is not present in the type signature `Promise<GraphQLResult> | Observable<object>`. This is because it is not present in the prototype of `Promise`.

To get the typings to work again you either need to return only observable from your `graphql()` function or cast its return value to `Observable<object>` (possible causing nullref). You can also wrap the calling code with `Observable.from()` which takes `Promiselike` as argument to normalize the signatures.

Comment: Can you please share some example on how you did this ?